# Flutter SocketException when uploading file to S3

Tags: ios, flutter, amazon-s3, socketexception, pre-signed-url

In Flutter iOS app, I am trying to upload a file to AWS S3 with Presigned URL.

it works with small file. However, it throws following error while uploading 5x MB file.
It's strange that the file can be uploaded successfully in iOS Simulator, but failed in real device.

Following is the error message.

```
flutter: Exception: SocketException: Read failed (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54), address = s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com, port = 54505
flutter: Stacktrace: #0      _NativeSocket.read (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:718:38)
#1      _RawSocket.read (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1457:22)
#2      _RawSecureSocket._readSocketOrBufferedData (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:974:22)
#3      _ExternalBuffer.writeFromSource (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1216:30)
#4      _RawSecureSocket._readSocket (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:983:16)
#5      _RawSecureSocket._readHandler (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:776:5)
#6      _RawSecureSocket._eventDispatcher (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:764:9)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#9      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
#10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
#11     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:265:7)
#12     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:766:19)
#13     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:642:7)
#14     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:588:5)
#15     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1399:33)
#16     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:919:14)
#17     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#18     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
```

My code as follow.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Response response = await http.put(
      url,
      headers: {
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      },
      body: await file.readAsBytes(),
    ).timeout(Duration(minutes: 5), onTimeout: () {
      developer.log("TIMEOUT");
      return null;
    });
```

Could anyone help to advise what am I do wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**
flutter doctor -v as below

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/leochiu/Documents/Sources/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (6 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/leochiu/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[!] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • S Box8Q40C • 0123456789 • android-arm • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: What flutter version are you running? Could you show your flutter doctor output?

Comment: @Nuts I have updated my post to include flutter doctor output

Comment: @LeoChiu, were you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution is adding the next header
`accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`